# What's the probability of cracking this cipher using partial information about the private key obtained from $k$ public keys?

Tags: public-key, provable-security, attack, decryption, information-theory

For the following cipher, what is the probability of someone without the private key generating a valid public key, using only information from a list of $k$ public keys previously generated with the private key?

This is the cipher:

*To generate the private encryption key, $Y$:* Let $X$ be an $n$ by $i$ matrix of random integers between $0$ and $9$, inclusive.
Let $Y$ be a vector of the $n$ real numbers defined by converting each row in $X$ to a real number between $0$ and $1$, e.g., $x_{1.} = (1, 2, 3)$ becomes $y_{1} = .123$.

*To generate public decryption keys, $W$:* Create a pair of random $j$-digit numbers between $0$ and $1$ inclusive, $a < b$. Let $Z =$ $R((Y - a/b)^2)$, where $R(.)$ returns the ascending rank order of reals, e.g., $R(23, 44, 2) = (2, 3, 1)$. Let $W = (a, b, Z)$.

*To decrypt with public key:* Test if $R((Y - w_{1}/w_{2})^2) = (w_{3}, w_{4}, ... , w_{n}).$

The probability of successfully generating a valid $W$ without any information about $Y$ is $1$ out of $n!$. What is the probability of successfully generating a valid $W$ with only the information from $k$ public keys previously generated from $Y$, in terms of $n$, $i$, $j$, and $k$?

Of note: According to @grand_chat's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414876/can-we-uniquely-define-for-arbitrary-real-valued-finite-sequence-x-infinite), we can uniquely define any $Y$ as the sequence of solutions to the infinite series of functions $R((Y - r)^2)$, as $r$ ranges over the rational numbers from $min(Y)$ to $max(Y)$. This implies that one cannot deduce a unique $Y$ from any finite $k$ of distinct $W$, but also that the probability of generating a valid $W$ increases with increasing $k$.

[probability of correctly guessing W corrected from $1/10^n$ to $1/n!$ per response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The probability of successfully generating a valid W without any information about Y is 1 out of $10^n$

Actually, it appears that the only information that's hard to guess in W is the Z component, which is some permutation of the values $(1, 2, 3, ..., n)$.  Hence, the probability of guessing successful is 1 in $n!$.

> What is the probability of successfully generating a valid $W$ with only the information from $k$ public keys previously generated from $Y$, in terms of $n, i, j$, and $k$?

The obvious approach would take a valid public key, and adjust the listed $a, b$ so that $a/b \approx a'/b'$; this will correspond (with quite good probability) to the same $Z$, and hence a valid $W$.  That is, with a single public key, we can generate another one.

Comment: Right on both counts! I corrected the probability in the post as you suggested. I agree the best strategy would be to make a trivially small alteration of the original a/b, which makes it a much less interesting problem than I'd thought it was. This is actually a major simplification of a related cypher that would not share this vulnerability. I simplified it because a) long questions are less likely to be answered, and b) @grand_chat's proof, while very clever, does not generalize beyond functions of this sort. I'll have to work out a new version of the cypher, but I'll post here to update.